# HTML forms, action attribute urls that are not absolute

Tags: php, html, forms, url

I've been teaching myself HTML and PHP using forms etc, and I decided to disect some high-profile websites to see how they setup their forms and I found that some used urls like "/" or "http://somewebsite.com/somepath/directory/" and did not point to a file like a PHP doc.

Taken that these forms use the POST method how does the browser know which file to post to? or does it use JS instead?

Comment: When browsing to a domain/folder the server automagically feeds the default file (index.html/index.php/etc)

Comment: It is most likely that what you labeled as a directory doesnt actually exist as a directory on the server.  The server is reading the url and directing to the proper server-side language file according to the server's rewrite rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a html tag for that action.
When you're building a form, you should use a special tag to tell the browser where to post the POST variables to.

You should use the "action" tag for this.

For more information check out the following url:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_elements.asp